# Shapes not drawing in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Can anyone help me out and tell me why the rectangle will not appear? The frame runs fine, but no shapes show up. I have tried doing this a couple of different ways, including with two separate classes, but all I get is an empty frame.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Surface extends JPanel 
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 30, 40);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Surface s = new Surface();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
        jf.setSize(600, 400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(s);
        s.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override a method, then annotate it correctly:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 30, 40);
}
```

then your IDE should tell you, that you're *not* overriding the `paintComponent` method correctly, because your parameter type `Graphics2D` is wrong.

This is the signature of the [original/parent method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) in `JComponent`:

> ```
> protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
> ```

And as you can see, it uses `Graphics` instead of `Graphics2D`. You're currently [*overloading*](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) `paintCompoent` instead of [*overriding*](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/method-overriding-in-java-with-example/) it. So change your parameter type to `Graphics` (and import `java.awt.Graphics`) and it will work:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 30, 40);
}
```

By the way, you're setting the visibility of your `jf` first and then add something to its contentpane. In some case this can cause trouble and the added components won't be visible until you repaint the frame (or you do something else, which cause the frame to repaint itself, like calling `pack()`). So it might be best to switch the order of these method calls in your `main` method:

```
Surface s = new Surface();
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
jf.setSize(600, 400);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jf.add(s);
//s.repaint(); // not needed anymore, because "jf" will repaint everything during the 'setVisible' call
jf.setVisible(true); // should almost always be the last thing you do
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, thanks. However, I made these changes to my code and it still does not work.

Comment: @Santi Make sure, that you use `java.awt.Graphics` as the parameter type and not any other `Graphics` version.

Comment: This is what it looks like now:

Comment: @Santi If I run that code, then I can see the red rectangle: http://imgur.com/kf1ZYGK

Comment: Thats weird, maybe somethings wrong with my eclipse?

Comment: @Santi No, works for me on Eclise, too, but I found a problem in your code with your `setVisible` call. Please check the edit.